# How can I resolve clang input unused in multiple indirection Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I'm trying to write a makefile that will enable a test suite runner, `test.c`, to run. However, I think my use of the `-c` flag is getting in the way.

```
all: parser

parser_out.o: parser_out.h parser_out.c
    clang -c -g parser_out.c
    
parser_loader.o: parser_loader.h parser_loader.c parser_mem.o
    clang -c -g lc4_mem.o parser_loader.c
    
parser_mem.o: parser_mem.h parser_mem.c
    clang -c -g parser_mem.c

parser: parser.c parser_mem.o parser_loader.o parser_out.o
    clang parser.c -g parser_mem.o parser_loader.o parser_out.o -o parser

tests: test

test_helpers.o: test_helpers.c test_helpers.h
    clang test_helpers.c -c -g

parser_loader.test.o: parser_loader.test.h parser_loader.test.c parser_loader.o test_helpers.o
    clang parser_loader.test.c -g parser_loader.o test_helpers.o

test: test.c parser_loader.test.o
    clang test.c -g parser_loader.test.o -o test
```

`make all` works as expected.

`make tests` fails and indicates that references to methods in `parser_mem.c` are undefined.

`make parser_loader.test.o` results in the same error as `make tests.`

If I include `parser_mem.o` directly in the linking of `parser_loader.test.o`, the errors caused by linking to my files disappear. But, an error indicating invalid linking to `GNU` remains:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

1. Why aren't my references through references being handled successfully?
2. Why is clang suddenly struggling to compile with system links?

Comment: Which file defines `main`?

Comment: Why would you expect any symbol from `parser_mem.c` to be visible in `test` if you don't include that file into the linker command? Also adding it to `*.o` file won't help. You need to add it to rule for `test`.

Comment: *Why is clang suddenly struggling to compile with system links?* What do you mean? What system links are you refering to?

Comment: First delet all object files. Then run make and look at the commands executed. Are they all correct? At least the command for "parser_loader.test.o" lacks the option "-c"...